# How to turn these C# foreach loops into LINQ to Objects and return a bool?

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I'm writing a .Net 3.5 C# script for Sony Vegas Pro. I've created this method which returns true if it finds a video event with the same timecode as a given audio event.

This works but I'm wondering if I could get rid of the foreach loops using LINQ. I'm just learning LINQ and I'm finding it quite hard so if you could explain your thought steps in getting to the solution, that'd be great.

```
private bool videoExistsWithSameStart(TrackEvent currentEvent)
    {
        //Look through each video track - we don't want audio tracks.
        var videoTracks = from t in myVegas.Project.Tracks
                          where t.IsVideo()
                          select t;

        foreach (Track t in videoTracks)
        {
            foreach (TrackEvent te in t.Events)
            {
                if (te.Start == currentEvent.Start)
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Resharper (http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) would do it for you - it has an option to auto translate foreach to LINQ queries, one of my favorite features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another alternative:

```
return myVegas.Project.Tracks
    .Where(track => track.IsVideo())
    .SelectMany(track => track.Events)
    .Any(trackEvent => trackEvent.Start == currentEvent.Start);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return videoTracks.Any(track => 
  track.Events.Any(pumpkin => 
    pumpkin.Start == currentEvent.Start));
```

Comment: Beat me to it, damn! +1 (Adding semicolon)

Comment: I believe it won't compile, `event` is a reserved word in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me, I don't have access to Visual Studio right now, but care to try?

```
return myVegas.Projects.Tracks.Any(t => t.IsVideo() && t.Events.Any(e => e.Start == currentEvent.Start));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return videoTracks.Any(t => t.Events.Any(te => te.Start == currentEvent.Start));
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what's easiest to do (for me at least) is trying to spell out what you're trying to do:

```
return videoTracks.Any(track => track.Events.Any(event => event.Start == currentEvent.Start));
```

What we want to know is does **videoTracks** have **Any** tracks where **Any** of its Events compare to the current one.